# Gson deserialize child as string in parent

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to deserialize this json response:

```
{  
    "_index":"miracle",
    "_type":"user",
    "_id":"AVpbIYg7NtDacQRf2Gz5",
    "_score":1.0,
    "_source":
    {  
        "username":"andrei23",
        "password":"andrei_23"
    }
}
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
public class HitDTO {

    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;

    @SerializedName("_source")
    private String source;
}
```

Is there some sort of annotation I can use or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create setters and getters for your fields.

Then, encapsulate your JSON object. So edit your class as below:

```
public class HitDTO {

   @SerializedName("_id")
   private String id;

   @SerializedName("_source")
   private HitSourceDTO source;

   // getters and setters
}
```

and

```
public class HitSourceDTO {

   @SerializedName("username")
   private String username;

   @SerializedName("password")
   private String password;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Finally, add a function to return your requested format of _source field:

```
function String getStringOfSource()
{
   return "username=" + source.username + " password=" + source.password;
}
```

Hope it helps you!

EDIT: I searched any kind of annotations for this purpose, I didn't find annotation to do exactly what you want.